# Using Basic Neural Network Subroutines (BNN) Accelerate

Tags: macos, accelerate-framework

I am trying to perform a 1x1 convolution using the Apple BNNS (Basic Neural Network Subroutine) library in Accelerate.

When I run on a 9x1 column vector, I get unexpected results.

Sample code posted at: https://gist.github.com/cancan101/5887cb93cc91a2d10e2bfd23284bb438 (a [modification of BNNS sample code.](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/samplecode/BasicNeuralNetworkSubroutines/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40017299-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2))

Expected Results:
Print numbers 0-8.

Actual Results:

```
o0: 0.000000
o1: 0.000000
o2: 0.000000
o3: 3.000000
o4: 0.000000
o5: 5.000000
o6: 0.000000
o7: 7.000000
o8: 0.000000
```

I suspect I am doing this right, but am open for feedback on the linked code.

Answer (score 0):

If you transpose to row vectors, you'd see expected output

from this:

```
i_desc.width = 1;
i_desc.height = 9;
i_desc.row_stride = 1;
```

to this:

```
i_desc.width = 9;
i_desc.height = 1;
i_desc.row_stride = 9;
```

same for output:

```
o_desc.width = 9;
o_desc.height = 1;
o_desc.row_stride = 9;
```

Result:

```
Input image stack: 9 x 1 x 1
Output image stack: 9 x 1 x 1
Convolution kernel: 1 x 1
o0: 0.000000
o1: 1.000000
o2: 2.000000
o3: 3.000000
o4: 4.000000
o5: 5.000000
o6: 6.000000
o7: 7.000000
o8: 8.000000
```

Comment: Right, I saw that worked, but am I doing something wrong? Or should what I have work

Comment: I don't understand what are you asking. Convolution is a matrix operation, when you transpose input, you can't expect result stay the same.

Comment: A 1x1 convolution (weight 1) on a row vector Should produce a matching row vector and a 1x1 convolution should produce a matching column vector .

Comment: But your kernel is [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0], and is sensitive to transpose. Identity kernel is [0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0]

Comment: Why is the kernel so large? Shouldn't it be of size 1? (https://gist.github.com/cancan101/5887cb93cc91a2d10e2bfd23284bb438#file-bnns_issue-c-L33-L42)

Comment: Yeah, my bad. I can't explain why 1x1 kernel breaks column image. If you widen the kernel to [0,1,0] and add x padding it works ok.